# Get query parameters that aren't dynamic route parameters in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-parameters, next-router

I have a component that needs to copy all of the query parameters from the URL. However I do not want to copy dynamic route parameters. So if it is used in a component like: `/pages/model/{modelId}.tsx` and the url is `/model/123456?page=2&sort=column&column=value`, I would like to retrieve the following object:

```js
{
  page: 2,
  sort: "column",
  column: "value"
}
```

I would use `useRouter().query` but this would include `modelId`. And the router object doesn't seem to have any other list of parameters.

So how would I distinguish regular URL parameters from dynamic route parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the built-in URL API instead:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);

url.searchParams.get("page"); // a string or null if not present
```

Going a little further, you could also wrap this in a hook for future use.

If you want the search parameters as an object, you could wrap it in `Object.fromEntries` too:

```js
const params = Object.fromEntries(new URL(window.location.href).searchParams);

params.page; // string or undefined now
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in my wording so I updated the question. Your answer is still very useful, but I will actually use something like `Object.fromEntries(new URL(window.location.href).searchParams)` in my project. If you would update your answer I would like to give you the point.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I stripped the unwanted key from the query object. In this case the dynamic url param.

I used lodash for this, but this could be perfectly done with Javascript only.

```
export const ignoreQueryParam = (obj, key) => _.omit(obj, key);
```

Applied to your case:

```
const router = useRouter();
const searchQuery = ignoreQueryParam(router.query, 'modelId');
```

I hope it helps.